# What is the difference between P(E) et P({E})

Tags: discrete-mathematics

I'm student in computer science.
In discrete mathematics we see the the notion of set (in mathematics)

So I have a question about **the difference between P(E) and P({E})**

---

P(E) is the set of subsets

**So what is P({E}) ?**

---

How to represent it on a Venn diagram ?

Comment: *ensemble* = set.

Comment: See [Power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) for $\mathcal P(E)$.

Comment: ok thanks, I corrected

Comment: The later is a collection of two elements.

Comment: $\mathcal P(E)$ is the set of subsets of set $E$, while $\mathcal P( \{ E \})$ is the set of subsets of set $\{ E \}$.

Comment: [Not duplicated](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1125598/power-set-of-a-set-containing-a-set), but quite related, you should have a look.

Comment: we can represent P(E) : https://i.imgur.com/SG066pw.png ans represent P({E}) : https://i.imgur.com/oSAMGPd.png ?

Answer (score 1):

So $P(\{E\}) = \{ \emptyset, \{E\}\}$

Comment: I can note {} --> ∅